# Не отображается enum в представлении

Tags: c#, razor

Всем привет. У меня такой вопрос. Я добавил enum в модель Task.cs и теперь вываливается ошибка "Constraint exception was unhandled by user code" в Index.cshtml в строчке @foreach (var t in Model).

```
public class Task
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Select a correct license")]
    public TaskStatus TaskStatus { get; set; }
}
```

enum TaskStatus

```
public enum TaskStatus
{
    [Display(Name = "New")]
    New,

    [Display(Name = "Closed")]
    Closed,

    [Display(Name = "InProcess")]
    Process,

    [Display(Name = "Need Confirm")]
    NeedConfirm
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
            @foreach (var t in Model)
        {
            <tr class="task-row-link" title="Edit" data-link="@Url.Action("Edit", new { id=t.Id})">
                <td class="centered"><p>@t.Id</p></td>
                <td class="centered"><p>@t.Title</p></td>
                <td class="centered"><p>@t.TaskStatus</p></td>
                <td class="centered"><p>@t.Author</p></td>
                <td class="centered"><p>@t.Description</p></td>
                <td class="centered">
                    <p>
                        <a href="/Home/Delete/@t.Id">Delete</a>
            </tr>
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если Вы объявляете перечисление следующим образом:

```
public enum TaskStatus
{
    [Display(Name = "New")]
    New,

    [Display(Name = "Closed")]
    Closed,

    [Display(Name = "InProcess")]
    Process,

    [Display(Name = "Need Confirm")]
    NeedConfirm
}
```

то значениями по умолчанию будет нумерация начиная с нуля (0, 1, 2, 3).

В Вашей модели Вы устанавливаете диапазон начиная с единицы:

```
[Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Select a correct license")]
public TaskStatus TaskStatus { get; set; }
```

Либо измените диапазон, либо задайте числовые значения для перечисления с единицы.

А еще проверьте, что Вы не используете случайно:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskStatus
```

Также, перед использованием `foreach` делайте проверку, чтобы не падало исключение:

```
@if (Model != null)
{
    foreach (var t in Model) // Model - должна быть коллекцией
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

Зайдите в контроллер, поставьте брэйкпоинт перед переходом на страницу и посмотрите, что Вы передаете в качестве модели, все ли заполнено.

Пожалуй, самым обязательным условием работы кода является то, что для того, чтобы работала строка `@foreach (var t in Model)` необходимо, чтобы модель (`Model`) - была коллекцией.

Также необходимо контролировать типы данных. Если в модели прописать определенный тип данных, то и в базе данных должен быть соответствующий. Иными словами, если в модели используется перечисление `TaskStatus` приводимое к `int`, то в базе данных должен быть тип `int`, но не `varchar`.

Comment: Я изменил на 
[Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Select a correct license")]
public TaskStatus TaskStatus { get; set; }
но проблема осталась. 
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskStatus это я не использую.

Comment: @Maksims, Model - это коллекция? Проверьте в контроллере, перед передачей модели в представление, чтобы значения были заполнены.

Comment: Да, это (Model) это коллекция 
@model IEnumerable<eTaskWebClient.Models.Task>

В контроллере вроде все поля заполнены 
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Tasks);
        }

Comment: Интересно я добавил проверку @if (Model != null),
но все равно ругается на  foreach (var t in Model)

Comment: Я почистил проэкт и теперь картина изменилась ;) Ругается на тоже самое, но в браузере появился exception Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The 'TaskStatus' property on 'Task' could not be set to a 'System.String' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'eTaskWebClient.Models.TaskStatus'.

Comment: И теперь в контроллере при отправке во view ошибка  Error = The function evaluation requires all threads to run.

Comment: @Maksims , там, где ты заполняешь поле TaskStatus - записываешь строку, а не значение из перечисления)))) проверь место заполнения в контроллере

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56349/discussion-between-denis-bubnov-and-maksims).